# How do I test result of dispatching async action creator in redux?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I have this action creator in react-redux which is dispatched after clicking a button. This AC removes user posts. Clicking a button runs action which first makes some firebase calls, and if they succeed it sends the action creator itself to redux to then make some changes in the redux store. When those changes are made my component is updated automatically and this removed post disappears. I want to test this functionality with jest/enzyme. I simulate pressing the remove button but I don't know how to await for firebase calls to end to then be able to test results that were made after firebase calls succeeded. I must emphasize that in the regular app everything works correctly. My problem is that my test simply doesn't wait for those calls to end and just finishes. How can I await for these firebase calls to end to then be able to test the results which were made after they succeeded?

```
// post component

// In post component onClick on a button just calls action like this: 

 onRemovePost({ index: post.index, authorModifiedEmail: author.modifiedEmail, hasUrl: !!post.url });


// action creator 

export const removePost = (post) => {
  const { index, authorModifiedEmail, hasUrl } = post;

  return async (dispatch) => {
    const updates = {};
    updates[`users/${authorModifiedEmail}/posts/posts/${index}`] = null;

    try {
      await fire.database().ref().update(updates);

      hasUrl && (await fire.storage().ref(`users/${authorModifiedEmail}/posts/${index}`).delete());

      dispatch({ type: actionTypes.REMOVE_POST, user: authorModifiedEmail, index });
    } catch (error) {
      failToast(error.message);
    }
  };
};

// test

test('removes post after clicking remove button', async () => {

  // initializing wrapper here with relevant props

  const postEditionIcon = findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'post-edition-icon').first();
  postEditionIcon.simulate('click');
  const removeBtn = findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'remove-btn');
  await removeBtn.simulate('click');

  const post = findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'post-component');
  expect(post.exists()).toBe(false);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
test('action creator is returned',()=>{ 
      return actionCreator().then((response) => {
       //write your assertion here
        const post = findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'post-component');
        expect(post.exists()).toBe(false);
        });
});
```

Comment: In your solution I call action creator manually. What I want is to just simulate clicking the button and then in some way await in my test after firebase request is done or somehow mock this firebase request to recive response immediately. Do you know any solution to that?